# Limit of a distribution fn

Tags: limits

I have this fonction defined by $$f_n(x)=\frac{\sqrt{n}e^{\frac{-nx^2}{4}}}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$$
How to find the limit of the distribution $$f_n$$ when n tends to infinity?Iknow that  $$\int_{R}^{}{e^{-x^2} dx=\sqrt{\pi}}$$